Can I adjust (and get slider-like control over) white balance control in my android phone (with native app or LMC 8.4)?
There's an obvious shift in white balance in my phone (visual compared to phone screen).
I'd like to adjust for it (and make it a preset).
I'd also like to be able to call up something like a slider for white balance so I can slide it until what I see on the screen matches what I see in front of me.
I understand also that there's an issue of the screen's calibration...
Thanks in advance!
The phone is a Uniherz Tank 3 pro. I have the native camera app, plus LMC 8.4.

It's not just your screen's calibration, it's also your brain's calibration of what your retinas are responding to. Cover one of your eyes with a red cellophane filter for several minutes until things look roughly the same through both eyes. It may take 1/2 hour. Then remove the filter and look at a blue object alternating between each eye. Not only does your brain adjust for different light, but it can cause certain hormones to be released in the retina that alter the comparative sensitivities of each type of retinal cone!

Or, if you don't want to mess with a filter, follow this link to demonstrate the same thing by looking at a colored screen with only one eye to recalibrate one but not the other eye.

On android you can control white balance vi standard camera application, select PRO mode, the select WB and you will see a wheel where you can select the colour temperature. Below you can see two photos on same surface with different colour temperature:



Interesting! It works perfectly, and exactly like that, on my old phone, which has Android 12.
BUT the new phone has Android 14, and when I select Pro and White Balance, I get a set of presets (daylight, twilight, cloudy, etc.), but not the wheel. Am I missing something? The wheel is perfect!

@WombatPete, these photos are from my phone, android 14. Maybe manufacturer decide to limit the options for WB.

Not impossible, but seems like it would be work for nothing - is that likely? Looking for ways around it. I imagine I could download a stock Android 14 app, right? But would there be a danger it wouldn't be properly connected to/integrated with all the cameras on this phone?

@WombatPete, honestly I am not sure you can download it, AFAIK it is available only for Google phones.

I wonder whether I can move it from my other phone...
...at the same time, there is LMC8.4, a version of the Google Pixel app, which is supposed to be a far better camera program, that can be downloaded to any android phone. I have it, but the settings are, as I wrote, somewhat arcane - I'm not sure yet what it can and can't do. The interface is different, so the advice here doesn't apply to it.

"On android" you might want to mention the device model (I'd assume recent Google Pixel?), Android version (already mentioned), and the camera app because manufacturers often customize their stock app.

@AndrewT., OnePlus 8T, standard app :)

Ah, I see, that's why it looks different from the stock Google Camera app on Pixel 3a.
